# Using browser profiles in selenium grid2

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I need to launch a firefox with different browser profiles based on the user requirement using selenium GRID.

How can I achieve this??

My framework is in Selenium-RC , so I couldn't make use of Webdriver DesiredCapabilities.

Does anyone has a solution for it??